# How to clear a JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json

How to clear the data from a **JSONArray**

there is nothing like:

```
jsonArray.clear();
```

not even:

```
jsonArray.remove(index);
```

which was suggested here:

[How do I remove a specific element from a JSONArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820551/how-do-i-remove-a-specific-element-from-a-jsonarray#answers)

Thank you

Comment: What is your exact need, you need to clear all data in you array or you need to remove a particular value in that array?

Comment: remove all the data from a JSONArray.

Comment: this is the link to the liberay that contains this function :-http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/JSONArray.html

Comment: What if that is in a Loop!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
jsonArray = new JSONArray(new ArrayList<String>());
```

Comment: You seem to have a confident answer, but I'm curious - will this lead to an unused JSONArray copy after every new? Similar to setting new values for a String variable?

Comment: This is like suggesting to clear a List object by doing list = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: this is obviously a mistake, this doesn't clear the array, it creates a new one so the previous one is not cleared at all, and if a reference to this object is kept on another variable, you'll be in big trouble.

Answer (score 7):

this is not a perfect answer but you can do like this,

```
jsonArray=new jsonArray("[{}]");
```

**EDIT**

As per suggestion in comment, you can also use below code:

```
jsonArray=new jsonArray();
```

Comment: Why not just `new JSONArray()`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think "new JSONArray()" is a good solution.

Sometimes you will need to access the JSONArray object from within an inner class,so you have to declare the JSONArray object as final, and then you can't assign it to a new one anymore.

The best way is to remove its elements by loop.

```
while(myjsonarray.length()>0)
{
    myjsonarray.remove(0);
}
```

You said "there is nothing like jsonArray.remove(index);", and also tagged this question with "java", "android"

But now I am using Android Studio 3.6.3, and JSONArray class has this method, and you can find it in [Android Studio official documents](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray?hl=en#remove(int)) as well. Therefore, I guess you should edit the title of the question like "why my android studio doesn't has the full methods of JSONArray class"

Comment: Call remove requires minimum API level 19

Answer (score 1):

Just made Local Variables

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonArray.put(productlist);
```

Every time jsonserver data add using local block if u declear global block then need for clear jsonarray

Answer (score 0):

I try everything but the only thing that worked for me was

```
jsonArray.clear();

or you can make it local variable again

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the library I have, there doesn't seem to be any way to call `clear()` of the private `ArrayList` inside of the `JSONObject`.  It does however have `public Object remove(int index)`.  I am just using `new JSONObject()` :(

Answer (score 0):

`jsonArray.clear();` This worked for me. I was using JSONArray from org.json (not org.json.simple) library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a while loop across the length of the JSONArray and at each time delete the first index. the loop will reach a stage when the length of the JSONArray is zero to show the JSONArray is not empty and and cleared.

```
while (optionArray.length() > 0) {
            optionArray.remove(0)
    }
```

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61910449/2227743).

Comment: You probably mean "... to show the JSONArray is empty and cleared."

Answer (score -4):

this is a one answer ,please try it:

```
jsonArray=[]
```