# Remove JSONobject from JSONarray in Android

Tags: android, json, android-layout

I have Dynamic JSON String i want to remove the last JSON object from the JSONARRAY in android. here is my dynamic JSON String in android. My json string is

> ("{\"findAllUsersResponse\": "+arguments[0].toString()+"}");

```
    {
    "findAllUsersResponse": [
        {
            "id": "kicJw2whXyuGjbNo936L",
            "name": "Fghhjj",
            "udid": "2AA120E3-7478-4AD4-9C68-9C0920669B84"
        },
        {
            "id": "NEF45TWNI6-Uc_r7938R",
            "name": "ssss",
            "udid": "1DD083C2-7F1D-4BB3-9AB9-691A5FD251CC"
        },
        {
            "id": "xuXY7Ah2-O-jL4Zk939D",
            "name": "Test",
            "udid": "A892E0AB-6732-4F42-BEFA-3157315E9EE4"
        },
        {
            "id": "w1FnBz8B9ciWUzBk939k",
            "name": "Aditi",
            "udid": "A892E0AB-6732-4F42-BEFA-3157315E9EE4"
        }

    ]
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837532/remove-json-object-from-jsonarray-jettison

Comment: jsonArray.remove(jsonArray.length()-1);

Comment: But i have dynamic Json string. And i want to remove only the last JSON object

Comment: Sorry but i want to do it before API19...

Comment: @raja- i want to do it before API 19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your String is not going to change and you only want last object to be deleted use **substring** and create new string.

```
 String finduserjson=  "{\"findAllUsersResponse\": "+arguments[0].toString()+"}");
    String t = finduserjson.substring(finduserjson.indexOf("{"), finduserjson.lastIndexOf(",{"));
    String j = "]}";
    finduserjson = t+j;
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Was facing a similar problem. There are no methods in the JSONarray object to get what you want. You could make a function to remove it. Saw this solution somewhere.

```
   public static JSONArray remove(final int index, final JSONArray from) {
    final List<JSONObject> objs = getList(from);
    objs.remove(index);

    final JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray();
    for (final JSONObject obj : objs) {
        jarray.put(obj);
    }

    return jarray;
}

public static List<JSONObject> getList(final JSONArray jarray) {
    final int len = jarray.length();
    final ArrayList<JSONObject> result = new ArrayList<JSONObject>(len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        final JSONObject obj = jarray.optJSONObject(i);
        if (obj != null) {
            result.add(obj);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `JSON` rather than `GSON` or `JACKSON`, then you cannot call `.remove()` method because you would not find it there.

Best thing you can do is, re-create a new `JSONArray` and add required `JSONObjects` in it.

Comment: But bro response is coming from server and i want to remove the last json object everytime.

Comment: It doesn't matter. What JSON library are you using?

Comment: So you mean to say it is not possible.

Comment: What I am saying is that, with JSON.org library this cannot be done. If you are using some other library (which you actually should), then all you need to do is call something like foo.remove(foo.size() - 1);