# Remove jsonobject from jsonarray

Tags: java, android

**I am new with android.I have simple string look like this:**

```
String json={"time":"12.00", "data":"25/01/2014","users":
[

{"id":1231,"title":"hello","url":"world"},
{"id":7656,"title":"hello","url":"world"},
{"id":3356,"title":"hello","url":"world"}

],"is_valid":false}
```

**And now I need to remove second users JSONObject:**

```
{"id":7656,"title":"hello","url":"world"}
```

**So I try following:**

```
JSONObject json=new JSONObject(json);
JSONArray users=json.getJSONArray("users");
users.remove(1);
json.put("users",users);
String new_json=json.toString();
```

**But unfortunately application forced close every time when I use users.remove(1); method please someone help me.**

**I need following string after removing object:**

```
String new_json=
tring json={"time":"12.00", "data":"25/01/2014","users":
[

{"id":1231,"title":"hello","url":"world"},
{"id":3356,"title":"hello","url":"world"}

],"is_valid":false}
```

*Thanks to all great programmers*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820551/how-do-i-remove-a-specific-element-from-a-jsonarray - took 20 seconds googling. Seems obvious that you cant remove something from an array

Comment: Thanks I got my solution