# org.json.JSONArray 's remove method is giving NoSuchMethodError exception

Tags: java, json

i am using following import org.json.JSONArray

```
String name = "manjeet";
if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("name").equals(name))
{
jsonArray.remove(i);
}
```

if I am calling this code from main in a class it is working fine but when I am calling it from UI it is behaving differently.

it is able to get inside if but while executing .remove(i) it is giving

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not 
be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json.JSONArray.remove(I)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

Comment: as the error says there so such method as `JSONArray.remove(I)` 
 , possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820551/how-do-i-remove-a-specific-element-from-a-jsonarray

Comment: I just want to know why this error is coming. The method is present there at compile time.

Comment: you can loop through your jsonarray and put the values you want in the `new arraylist` since there is no such method as `jsonArray.remove ` you are confusing it with javascript

Comment: I am already using what you are suggesting and the API I am using 'org.json.JSONArray' does have remove(I) method. Anyways thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I have added an answer also for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:** jar conflict

It may happen sometime that same class is provided by multiple jar's.

In my case org.json.JSONArray is also present in 'jackson-datatype-json-org' but that is having an older version of the class, in which remove method is not available.

Due to this the 'remove' method was avilable at compile time or while running the same code from main, but when I was running it from UI it was picking the class from 'jackson-datatype-json-org'.

So that is the reason I was getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError exception.

**Solution:** we can use exclusions tag in dependency('jackson-datatype-json-org') to remove the class that we don't want to use.

**Example:**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-datatype-json-org</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.8</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.bundles</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove particular element from your `jsonArray` you will have to create an `Arraylist` and store the values you want from the jsonArray instead.

You can implement it like:

```
String name = "manjeet";
ArrayList<String> final_list = new ArrayList<>();
if (! jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("name").equals(name))
{
    final_list.add(i);
}
// now you can use the final_list instead of using jsonArray.
```

Notice the `!` in `if condition`.